# Extract value from list of dictionaries in dataframe using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have this dataframe with 4 columns. I want to extract resourceName (i.e IDs ) in one separate column. I tried various methods and loops but unable to seperate it.

Dataset:

| Username | Event name | Resources |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ-DEV_ENV_POST_function | StopInstances | [{"resourceType":"AWS::EC2::Instance","resourceName":"i-05fbb7a"}] |
| XYZ-DEV_ENV_POST_function | StartInstances | [{"resourceType":"AWS::EC2::Instance","resourceName":"i-08bd2475"},{"resourceType":"AWS::EC2::Instance","resourceName":"i-0fd69dc1"},{"resourceType":"AWS::EC2::Instance","resourceName":"i-0174dd38aea"}] |

I want one more column IDs which will have IDS from Resource column and ll look like this:

| Username | Event name | Resources | IDS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ-DEV_ENV_POST_function | StopInstances | [{"resourceType":"AWS::EC2::Instance","resourceName":"i-05fbb7a"}] | i-05fbb7a" |
| XYZ-DEV_ENV_POST_function | StartInstances | [{"resourceType":"AWS::EC2::Instance","resourceName":"i-08bd2475"},{"resourceType":"AWS::EC2::Instance","resourceName":"i-0fd69dc1"},{"resourceType":"AWS::EC2::Instance","resourceName":"i-0174dd38aea"}] | i-08bd2475 , i-0fd69dc1 , i-0174 |

Here is output of data.head(2).to_dict():

{'Date':
{0: '28-02-2022', 1: '28-02-2022'},
'Event name':
{0: 'StopInstances', 1: 'StartInstances'},
'Resources':
{
0: '[{"resourceType":"AWS::EC2::Instance","resourceName":"i-05fbb7a"}]',
1: '[{"resourceType":"AWS::EC2::Instance","resourceName":"i-08bd2475"},{"resourceType":"AWS::EC2::Instance","resourceName":"i-0fd69dc1"},{"resourceType":"AWS::EC2::Instance","resourceName":"i-0174dd38aea"}]'},
'User name': {0: 'XYZ-DEV_ENV_POST_function', 1:
'XYZ-DEV_ENV_POST_function'}}

Thanks and Regards

Comment: dont include images. Include the data itself

Comment: Hey.. Thanks for the suggestion..!! I hope its more clear now.

Comment: Check the solution

Comment: You will have to include the output of `df.head(2).to_dict()` in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['ID'] = df['Resources'].apply(lambda x: ','.join([i['resourceName'] for i in eval(x)]))

         Date  ...                                   ID
0  28-02-2022  ...                            i-05fbb7a
1  28-02-2022  ...  i-08bd2475,i-0fd69dc1,i-0174dd38aea
```

Comment: I am facing error when executed same command: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-e53de9261750> in <module>()
----> 1 data3.assign(ID = data3['Resources'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['resourceName']))

4 frames
<ipython-input-15-e53de9261750> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 data3.assign(ID = data3['Resources'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['resourceName']))

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Also I do have multiple dictionaries in a list in second row - and all IDs required.

Comment: @Deepanshikashyap just include what i requested and will provide a solution

Comment: Updated my question with required details..!

Comment: @Deepanshikashyap CHECK UPDATE